# Ubuntu - how to copy files and folders which contain special characters

Tags: command-line, copy, exfat

I have a filesystem mounted read only which has many files with special characters like `&`, `(` and `"`. I would like to copy recursively all files and folders to an external exFat volume using `cp -R` but when I try I get many errors which look like:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/media/How About Better Parents?.pdf’: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to copy these filenames which contain valid but special characters?

Comment: Those are not valid characters for the system you copy it to. Remove the "?" from this file (and the &, ( and ")

Comment: How would I remove the special characters?  The source file is on a read-only filesystem so I can't do a two step process like run detox on the source files and then a standard cp.  Is there a script which will 'clean' the filenames if needed for exFat and then copy recursively?

Comment: Because the system you want to put it on does not want them. Probably no need for a script but 1 sed command needed before the "cp"(?) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in steps, creating a list of the files and the new name for each.  You would probably have to create the target directories first.  If the directory structure is relatively flat you could do that manually with `mkdir -p path`.  If there are many directories but they don't contain spaces or illegal target characters you could use (say from /dvd to /media)

```
cd /media ; ( cd /dvd ; find . -type d ) | xargs mkdir -p
```

This places you in the target directory (ready for the `mkdir`) and then lists all directories below the source directory, sending those to `mkdir`.  You may be able to use `find` option `-print0` together with `xargs` option `-0` if you need spaces in directory names.

Then use `find` to create the list of files to be copied, say with

```
cd /dvd ; find . -type f | sed 's/\(.*\)/cp "\1" "\1"/' > /tmp/copy.sh
```

Then edit the file `/tmp/copy.sh` replacing all illegal characters in the target names.  For each file name the `sed` command inserts `cp` before it, then the filename inside double quotes (source), and the filename inside double quotes again (target).  Once you have this looking acceptable make `copy.sh` executable and run it.

Disclaimer: as always it's possible to copy files to the wrong place, fill a file system, etc, so try a few commands manually and check the result before running a whole mass of them.  You could test the `xargs mkdir` command by trying `xargs echo mkdir` first to see what it will do.

Comment: This seems like a great solution and deserves an upvote (at the very least). Running the find command in a subshell with a different working directory is a clever idea for creating the directory structure – though I’d suggest using the `-print0` option with the `find` command and `-0` for the `xargs` so that it can handle directory names with spaces. Upvoted.

Comment: Yes, a very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

You’ll have to use a filesystem other than exFAT. According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT), the allowed characters in filenames are:

> Unicode UTF-16 except
>
> - U+0000 (NUL) through U+001F (US)
> - `/` (slash)
> - `\` (backslash)
> - `:` (colon)
> - `*` (asterisk)
> - `?` (Question mark)
> - `"` (quote)
> - `<` (less than)
> - `>` (greater than)
> - `|` (pipe)

Comment: @Rinzwind No need. Jeffrey has taken care of that. Go give him an upvote!